# KineticJS difference between moveTo and Draw methods

Tags: kineticjs

What's the main difference between the two methods `moveTo(Kinetic.Layer)` and `Draw()`? After a drag and drop for example, I have to draw the layer using one of them.

What makes this

```
layer.add(shape); 
layer.draw();
```

different from this: `shape.moveTo(layer)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This:**

```
shape.moveTo(layer2)
```

**is the equivalent of this:**

```
shape.remove();
layer2.add(shape);
layer2.draw();
```

Comment: The second code, removing the shape, you mean from a layer other than layer2 ?

Comment: Yes, shape.remove() removes the shape from a layer other than layer2.